# Troubles installing Haskell Platform

Tags: haskell, haskell-platform

I was trying to to install Haskell Platform 2014 2.0 but I can't really understand what am I supposed to do to make it work and there seems to be no useful documentation on the site.
I downloaded the binary dist from the site, unpacked it, launched the 'activate-hs' script and got this:

```
Haskell set to:
    GHC         /home/riccardo/usr/local/haskell/ghc-7.8.3-x86_64
    Haddocks    file:///home/riccardo/usr/local/haskell/ghc-7.8.3-x86_64/doc/frames.html
    Other doc   file:///home/riccardo/usr/local/haskell/ghc-7.8.3-x86_64/share/doc/ghc/html/index.html

Symlinks for command line tools (ghc, cabal, etc..) added to:
    /usr/local/bin
```

Even running in --verbose tells me nothing more about what's going on, it just returns a list of all the files.
What should I do?

EDIT:

```
riccardo@eos:~$ whereis ghc
ghc: /usr/local/bin/ghc
```

If I go to `/usr/local/bin` the symlinks are there and they point to the respective files in `/home/riccardo/usr/local/haskell/ghc-7.8.3-x86_64/bin`, but in the property window it says they are broken, what does this mean?

Also, if I get into `home/riccardo/usr/local/haskell/ghc-7.8.3-x86_64/bin` and try to launch the scripts directly from there, it still won't work:

```
riccardo@eos:~/usr/local/haskell/ghc-7.8.3-x86_64/bin$ ./ghci-7.8.3
./ghci-7.8.3: line 2: /usr/local/haskell/ghc-7.8.3-x86_64/bin/ghc-7.8.3: File o directory non esistente
```

`File o directory non esistente` = `file or directory does not exist`

Comment: That doesn't look like an error message. That looks like the installation succeeded and it is telling you where it placed all of its files... You can make sure by running `/usr/local/bin/ghc --version`.

Comment: Yeah I know there is no error message, but still that's not working.
I mean, it keeps running the older version(7.4.1) which I had installed before, while cabal and the rest appears to be 'not found'

Comment: @SchrodingersHippo maybe remove the older version?

Comment: There's a chance `/usr/local/bin` isn't on your `PATH`. Other than that, do you run activate-hs as root?

Comment: Can you check if `/usr/local/bin/ghc` is 7.4 or 7.8?  What happens if you run `whereis ghc`?  Look at your `PATH` variable as Cubic said (e.g. using `echo $PATH` in Bash) and see if something else is taking precedence.

Comment: @alternative just removed everything and started from the beginning: nothing changed.
@Rufflewind @Cubic this is my path: `/home/riccardo/anaconda3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:`

Comment: Note that the above message says that `ghc` is located at `/home/riccardo/usr/local/haskell/ghc-7.8.3-x86_64` - i.e. in the directory `/home/riccardo/usr/local/haskell` - and I don't see that in your PATH.

Comment: updated the original post.

Answer (score 0):

For posterity, if you're installing the generic-linux binary package as this appears to be describing, you cannot just run activate-hs. Rather you run `install-haskell-platform.sh` which puts everything in the proper place. Following that, you can use the installed `activate-hs` in the future if you want to swap between different versions...